# CUDA: while loop index correctness

Tags: optimization, cuda, while-loop

This kernel is doing the right thing giving me the correct result. My problem is more in correctness of the while loop if I want to improve the performance. I tried several configuration of blocks and threads but if i'm going to change them, the while loop won't give me the correct result.
The results i obtained changing the configuration of the kernel are that firstArray and secondArray won't be filled completely (they will have 0 inside the cells). Both arrays must be filled with the curValue obtained from the *if loop*.

Any advice is welcomed :)

Thank you in advance

```
#define N 65536

__global__ void whileLoop(int* firstArray_device, int* secondArray_device)
{   
    int curValue = 0;
    int curIndex = 1;

    int i = (threadIdx.x)+2;

    while(i < N) {
        if (i % curIndex == 0) {
            curValue = curValue + curIndex;
            curIndex *= 2;
        }
        firstArray_device[i] = curValue;
        secondArray_device[i] = curValue;
        i += blockDim.x * gridDim.x;
    }
}

int main(){

  firstArray_host[0] = 0;
  firstArray_host[1] = 1;

  secondArray_host[0] = 0;
  secondArray_host[1] = 1;


  // memory allocation + copy on GPU

  // definition number of blocks and threads
  dim3 dimBlock(1, 1);
  dim3 dimGrid(1, 1);

  whileLoop<<<dimGrid, dimBlock>>>(firstArray_device, secondArray_device);

  // copy back to CPU + free memory
}
```

Comment: This isn't really an optimization problem - it is one of correctness, isn't it?

Comment: I guess you are right. I will change the title of the post.

Comment: I don't really understand the question... What exactly is it you want advice on? You say that your kernel works correctly but that you have a problem with "correctness"?

Comment: I meant, if I change the settings of the kernel to improve the performance, I won't have the correct indexes inside the arrays. So I was wondering if there is another way to obtain the same results inside the arrays with a different kernel setting.

Comment: @RogerDahl: Basically his code can only ever work when run serially (ie. one thread). Try running more than that and it breaks in several ways, both because of buggy code and an incorrect algorithm.

Comment: @talonmies, yep he needs to parallelize his algorithm, as otherwise he would have multiple threads righting to the same global memory space...

Comment: Aha! I think the question needs a new title. "How do I parallelize this algorithm?"

Comment: I guess "correct" is an okay term.  The code is parallel, but only works for a single block (so it's pretty lightly threaded, not very parallelized) because there is an error in his algorithm.  Dado did make an attempt to parallelize -- just a lot of code was missing and I don't quite understand how the algorithm in its current form will be accelerated by all the footwork to put it on the GPU.  I would imagine his actual problem is more complex and that he's a researcher trying to trim down/anonymize his code for proprietary reasons -- my guess based on my own experience, at least. :)

Comment: @JasonR.Mick, you are right! unfortunately I can't write so much about my code because the actual problem is bigger that this and there are proprietary parts inside it. Anyway, I will follow the instructions below and try to find a new solution of the issue!

Answer (score 4):

You have a data dependency issue here which hinders you to do some meaningful optimization. The variables curValue and curIndex are changed within the while loop and feed forward into the next run. As soon as you try to optimize the loop you will find you in a situation where this variables have different states and the result is changed.

I do not really know what you try to achieve, but try to make the while loop indepdent to the values of a former run of the loop to avoid the dependencies. Try to separate the data into threads and data chunks in a way that the indizes and values are calculated on the environment states like threadIdx, blockDim, gridDim...

Also try to avoid conditional loops. It is better to use for loops with a constant number of runs. This is also easier to optimize.

Comment: I'm just a curious reader who stumbled upon this without any CUDA knowledge. Why do you say "try to avoid conditional loops"? Is that objectively right in CUDA? Or in any other language? Is that some sort of best-practice? Why?

Comment: It technical related and best practice: 1) If you really have a constant number of runs in a for loop, the compile has a chance for safe optimization like loop-enrollment, cache optimization,... This is true for a CUDA and OpenCL compiler, too. 2) If you have a conditional loop, the condition itself becomes very easy a data dependency. This can be true for a c-style for loop, too, but when you use it as a counting loop, it is not. 3) The best way for CUDA and OpenCL is to have a constant set of input data and a fixed function to calculate the output.

Comment: Good points Rick-Rainer!  Also, conditional loops are a great way to create thread divergence, which kills your parallel performance by creating scheduling difficulties.  Even if the code is correct, you want all your threads to be doing the same work ideally.  Short conditionals evaluated by all threads are not a big deal, but a loop has different threads finishing at different times may lead to a lot of divergence and slow performance.  Avoiding divergent conditional logic in general is a good CUDA paradigm.

Answer (score 2):

A few things:

1. You left out the code you used to declare your global arrays on the
   device.  It would be helpful to have this info.
2. Your algorithm is
   not thread-safe when multiple blocks are used.  In other words, if you are running multiple
   blocks, not only would they be doing redundant work (thus giving
   you no gains), but they would also likely at some point try to write
   to the same global memory locations, creating errors.
3. Your code is thus
   correct when only one block is used, but this makes it rather pointless ... you're running a serial, or lightly-threaded operation on a parallel device.  You cannot run on all your available resources (multiple blocks on multiple SMPs without memory conflicts (see below)...

Currently there are two main issues with this code from a parallel standpoint:

1. `int i = (threadIdx.x)+2;` ...yields a starting index of `2` for a
   single thread; `2` and `3` for two threads in a **single** block, and so on.  I doubt this is
   what you want as the first two positions (`0`, `1`) are never getting
   addressed. (Remember, arrays start at index `0` in C.)
2. Further, if you include **multiple** blocks (say 2 blocks
   each with one thread) then you would have multiple duplicate indices
   (e.g. for 2 b x 1 t --> indices b1t1: `2`, b1t2: `2`), which when you used the index
   to write to global memory would create conflicts and errors. Doing something like `int i = threadIdx.x + blockDim.x * blockIdx.x;` would be the typical way to correctly calculate your indices so as to avoid this issue.
3. Your
   final expression `i += blockDim.x * gridDim.x;` is okay, because its
   adds a number equivalent to the total # of threads to i and thus
   does not create additional clashing or overlap.
4. Why use the GPU to shuffle memory and do a trivial computation?  You may not see much speedup versus a fast CPU, when you factor in the time to take your arrays onto and off of the device.

Work on problems 1 and 2 if you wish, but beyond that consider your overall goal and what exactly kind of algorithm you are trying to optimize and come up with a more parallel-friendly solution -- or consider whether GPU computing really makes sense for your problem.

Comment: Great analysis! I had no time for this. You are absolutely right, as far as I can see.

Comment: You could always, make me the answer then. ;)

Comment: @JasonR.Mick thank you for the analysis! Very helpful! But I have something to say: about the point 1, I need to get the threadIdx.x starting from 2 because the firsts two cells of the array are 0 and 1 (my bad that I didn't specify in the post - I will change it). In the end you said something that I might follow. I the lasts three days I really thought if it worth to use the GPU for these kind of computations. Anyway, thank you again

Answer (score 1):

To parallelize this algorithm, you need to come up with a formula that can directly calculate the value for a given index in the array. So, pick a random index within the range of the array, then consider what the factors are that go into determining what the value will be for that location. After finding a formula, test it by comparing output values for random indexes with the calculated values from your serial algorithm. When that is correct, create a kernel that starts out by selecting an unique index based on it's thread and block indexes. Then calculate the value for that index and store it in the corresponding index in the array.

A trivial example:

Serial:

```
__global__ void serial(int* array)
{
  int j(0);
  for (int i(0); i < 1024; ++i) {
    array[i] = j;
    j += 5;
}

int main() {
  dim3 dimBlock(1);
  dim3 dimGrid(1);
  serial<<<dimGrid, dimBlock>>>(array);
}
```

Parallel:

```
__global__ void parallel(int* array)
{
  int i(threadIdx.x + blockDim.x * blockIdx.x);
  int j(i * 5);
  array[i] = j;
}

int main(){
  dim3 dimBlock(256);
  dim3 dimGrid(1024 / 256);
  parallel<<<dimGrid, dimBlock>>>(array);
}
```